# LVM + use the space of the OS in order to increase the partition

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, lvm, vmware

from the lsblk
I have the following output

```
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda                8:0    0  300G  0 disk 
├─sda1             8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2             8:2    0 99.5G  0 part 
  ├─vgd-lv_root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vgd-lv_swap 253:1    0 15.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vgd-lv_var  253:2    0   30G  0 lvm  /var
  └─vgd-zero    253:3    0  3.9G  0 lvm  
sr0               11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

we want to increase the /var , but Pfree is 0

```
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  vgd lvm2 a--  99.51g    0
```

is any option to increase the /var

because sda is 300G , and maybe we can take the space from sda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have 200 GiB of unallocated space in `/dev/sda` which you could use. There are two approaches you can use, depending on whether you need to keep the system online while this is happening.

- Without needing to unmount anything or reboot, you can create a third partition in `/dev/sda`:

  1. create a partition using your favourite partitioning tool;
  2. create a PV on it: `pvcreate /dev/sda3`;
  3. add it to your volume group: `vgextend vgd /dev/sda3`.
- Or with a reboot, extend `/dev/sda2`:

  1. using your favourite partitioning tool, either extend `/dev/sda2` (if this is possible, *e.g.* with Parted), or delete `/dev/sda2` and re-create it with exactly the same starting sector;
  2. reboot;
  3. resize the PV: `pvresize /dev/sda2`.

You’ll now have nearly 200 GiB available in your VG, and you’ll be able to extend your LV, *e.g.* using `fsadm`.

Comment: ok , but lets we we already did : pvcreate /dev/sda3 and vgextend vgd /dev/sda3 , what is the procedure to fallback  ?

Comment: If no space is yet allocated from the `/dev/sda3` LVM PV, just `vgreduce vgd /dev/sda3`, then either `pvremove /dev/sda3` or just overwrite/delete the sda3 partition with whatever you want. If you've already used some of the new space (i.e. in the `pvs` output, PSize and PFree are no longer equal for sda3), then you'll need to either use `pvmove` to move the allocations somewhere else, or undo what you did to use the space so that sda3 PV is again fully free before removing it from the VG.

Comment: Why would you want to fall back if you’ve already added `/dev/sda3`? That’s what I describe in the first approach...

Comment: when we do pvresize /dev/sda2 , we get 
  Physical volume "/dev/sda2" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized